# Lookup columns with JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery

I have two lists with one column that is a lookup column. How can i bind the two lists together with JavaScript or can i retrieve the data from both lists with the lookup column and JavaScript? Or what is the potentials?

Comment: not clear. please add more description

Comment: Please clarify your question.